# SVN : how to compare specific file in head revision with some other older revision?

Tags: svn

I have this file `js/xyz.js`. Currently its a `head` revision (say r7700).

I want to compare this file with `js/xyz.js` (same file) from older revision (say r7600)

Is there any way?

**I want to know, how to do it with `CLI ( Command line interface )`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: `svn diff -r7600 js/xyz.js`

Answer (score 1):

To compare the current version with revision 7600 use:

```
svn diff -r 7600 js/xyz.js
```

You can also use

```
svn diff -r 7600:7700 js/xyz.js
```

to explicitly compare revision 7600 wth 7700

Comment: Selected JNDPNT's answer since he was the first to answer (+1) :)